# Can't find an element even though its brother element is found in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to get the content from a tag, but it raised  `NoSuchElement` even though getting it from an another tag with the same level is successful.

This is the link to website: https://soundcloud.com/pastlivesonotherplanets/sets/spell-jars-from-mars

This is the html code that I access to:

```html
<div class="fullHero__tracksSummary">
      <div class="playlistTrackCount sc-font">
            <div class="genericTrackCount sc-font large m-active" title="16 tracks">
                  <div class="genericTrackCount__title">16</div>
                  <div class="genericTrackCount__subtitle"> Tracks </div>
                  <div class="genericTrackCount__duration sc-type-small sc-text-body sc-type-light sc-text-secondary">56:07</div>
            </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the playlist's duration with this code:

```py
try:
   tmp=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='fullHero__tracksSummary']") 
   duration=tmp.find_element_by_class_name("genericTrackCount__duration sc-type-small sc-text-body 
   sc-type-light sc-text-secondary").get_attribute('textContent')
   print(duration)
except:
   print("None")
```

It raised error `NoSuchElement` even though the other two tags was successful.

What is the problem and how can I fix it?

Thank your for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try directly using xpath `//div[contains(@class, 'duration')]` OR
`//div[contains(@class, 'playlistTrackCount')]/descendant::div[contains(@class, 'duration')]`

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the page, you probably need to wait for the element to load.

You can use either `time.sleep(5)` 5 being the number of seconds to wait or `WebDriverWait(driver, 20)` with an expected condition

so your code would look like

```
import expected_conditions as EC
    
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, '"genericTrackCount__duration sc-type-small sc-text-body 
       sc-type-light sc-text-secondary"))).text
```

Also maybe the  `get_attribute('textContent')` is failing, you can just use `.text`